# Magneto Newsletter mails are not going

Tags: magento, cron, magento-1.9

I am having Magento 1.9.3 and i am new to Magento.
My newsletter subscription is not working. I have checked all things in magento configuration. Seems its the trouble with cron on server. But with out knowing i do not want to make changes on server. I am using A2 hosting provider, and there is a cron set like this, which runs for every 30 mins.

```
/bin/cagefs_enter.proxied php /home/lasakico/public_html/cron.php 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
```

I am not sure what is the problem, either its the problem with cron or magento.

I have checked magento configuration->Advanced->System->Cron, where values are stored for Generate Schedules Every : 15. and rest are like 20, 15, 10, 60,600

Please let me know if anything is not clear in the question. I will ans them.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

Magento has a script called cron.php which handles all of the timed jobs that your Magento store has to do. In this list is the task of sending out newsletters. You have to set up your server crontab to run this cron.php script at regular intervals (eg 5 minutes).

Once you do this, you should find that your newsletter will be sent out as expected

- Open up an SSH session with your server. (If you can’t do this you
  are going to have to ask your hosts to do this for you instead).
- Browse to the document root of your magento store, the folder with
  cron.php in there
- enter the command

  `pwd` This command gives you the current full path. Write this down
  somewhere
- enter the command

  which php

  This command gives you the path to your PHP binary. Write this down somewhere
- enter the command

  crontab -e

  This opens up your crontab editor which is the system for scheduling
  tasks on Linux
- hit the [i] key to go into insert mode on the crontab editor (vi
  basically)
- on a new line paste the following, but replacing the paths with the
  paths you got before

  */5 * * * * /path/to/php -f /path/to/cron.php
- Hit [esc] then type the command

  :wq

  This saves the crontab or cntrl + x and Y
- Create a newsletter and schedule it to send in 2 minutes time.